# how to import a jsp from temp directory in jstl

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, dynamic, tempdir

I have some dynamically generated jsp content I'd like to (jstl) `c:import` into another jsp page. Currently I have the dynamically generated jsp written to a file in the servlet temp directory (`javax.servlet.context.tempdir`) but can't work out how I can import it since it is outside the servlet context.
Is there a way to import a jsp from the servlet temp directory, or can I somehow pre-process the jsp content without it having to be written to a file?
Previously I had this written to a file in the servlet context using `getRealPath()`, but obviously it won't work in all deployments.

Thanks for any help!

[update] Ok, so I can't write a file except under a temp directory, and I can't use a jsp directly from a temp directory.
Is there a way of passing the jsp content to the default jsp servlet directly to get the HTML output? How do you typically use dynamically generated jsp files?
Can I implement a filter to pass in the jsp content from the tempo directory? Can I override with a HttpServletResponseWrapper or something?

Comment: I ended up just refactoring so I didn't need to generate jsp dynamically, and just use a jsp with more dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

That context attribute is of type `File`, which provides a `toURI` method. See if something like this works:

```
<%
File tempdir = application.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
URI tempdirURI = tempdir.toURI();
application.setAttribute("tempdirURI", tempdirURI.toString());
%>
...
<c:import url="${tempdirURI}/path/to/generated.jsp"/>
```

If it does, it would actually be better practice to put the creation of tempdirURI into a `ServletContextListener`. Or create an EL function...

Comment: This way JSP won't be parsed but displayed as plain text.